# Difference DNX and .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

I couldn't find any answer online so I try it here: What is the difference between the DNX (.NET Execution Environment) and the .NET Core?

I know that the DNX is the SDK and also used to execute code and the .NET Core contains the CoreFX (Libraries) and the CoreCLR (the common language runtime).

But I still don't get what it is precisely about between DNX and the .NET Core.

Comment: Read:
https://github.com/aspnet/dnx and 
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr

Comment: @Asik I know that but there's something i don't completely get yet... And I don't know what that could be

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that .NET Core is the core Common Language Runtime and various .NET libraries used in .NET applications. This would be things like `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`, `Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor`, etc.).

DNX is the .NET executioner, which is responsible for running your .NET application. Basically, you would install one or more DNX (clr, coreclr, mono) versions. Then you would build your application and type something like `dnx run` or `dnx web` from the command-line to run your application.

There is also DNVM (the .NET version manager), which is the tool used to maintain (install, upgrade, uninstall, etc.) versions of DNX. You would do this by entering commands like `dnvm upgrade`, `dnvm install <dnx_version>`, `dnvm uninstall <dnx_version>`, `dnvm use <dnx_version>`, etc.

And then there is DNU (the .NET Utilities manager), which manages the dependencies your application relies on located in your project.json file every time you add/remove new dependencies in your project.json file, `dnu restore` would need to be run in order to update the dependencies your application relies before running `dnx run` or `dnx web`.

I've heard that `dnx`, `dnvm`, `dnu` will all be under `dotnet` soon as .NET 5 is now being called .NET Core 1.0